# Is "I accept" in the active or passive voice?

Tags: terminology

In the following sentence written in a letter from Sir Michael Fallon to Theresa May, is "I accept" in the passive or active voice?

"Many of these have been false but **I accept** that in the past I have fallen below the high standards that we require the armed forces that I have to honour to represent".

Comment: How could it be passive? Where is a verb "be" and a past participle?

Comment: As a general rule (I'm sure there are exceptions), when "I" appears in a sentence then the associated verb is active.

Comment: @HotLicks How is that a rule? "I am attacked" (passive)

Answer (score 1):

It is in the active voice. The subject, "I", performs the action denoted by the verb, "accept".

For example, see: https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/activepass.htm

The passive voice version would have been, "It has been accepted by myself that in the past..."

As you can imagine, in my experience talking about oneself in the passive voice is not common.